# Custom model binding when using withTrashed method on Route declaration and resolveRouteBinding in Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-routing

I am having a problem with **implicit model binding** on **routes** for **Soft Deleted Models**. When using the `withTrashed` method, the `resolveRouteBinding` method in the **Model** is NOT called. When `withTrashed` method is removed from the **route declaration**, the method `resolveRouteBinding` is called as expected.

### Steps To Reproduce:

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('user/{user}', function(SoftDeletedModel $user) {
    dd($user);
})->withTrashed(); //withTrashed is used
```

Models/SoftDeletedModel.php

```
use SoftDeletes;

public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null) {
    dd("Successfully Substituted Bindings when using WithTrashed."); //This is not displayed.
    return parent::resolveRouteBinding($value, $field);
}
```

Is this a known bug or where am I going wrong?
There also exists an [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/39799) on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this method `resolveSoftDeletableRouteBinding` instead of `resolveRouteBinding`.

```php
    /**
     * Retrieve the model for a bound value.
     *
     * @param mixed $value
     * @param string|null $field
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function resolveSoftDeletableRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
    {
        
         return parent::resolveSoftDeletableRouteBinding($value, $field);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [Laravel v8.55.0](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/38348), `withTrashed()` is supported in route:

```php
Route::post('/user/{user}', function (ImplicitBindingModel $user) {
    return $user;
})->middleware(['web'])->withTrashed();
```

Comment: Works pefectly!